# Array.prototype.find() returns undefined in async function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, asynchronous, promise

I have an issue with the `Array.prototype.find()` method. It doesn't seem to work properly when it is used in `$http request..` I've tried everything that came to mind but it always returns undefined. I guess the bug is there because I logged `response.data` and `user_to_find` before defining `found_user` and their values are as expected.

**So I have this service:**

```
app.service('UserService', ['$http','$q', function($http, $q) {
  return {
    findUser: function(user_to_find) {
      let defer = $q.defer();
      $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/users'
      }).then(function(response){
        let found_user = response.data.find(acc=>{ //found_user is always undefined
          acc.username == user_to_find;
        })
        defer.resolve(found_user);
      }),function(response) {
        defer.reject(response);
        console.log("Error finding user");
      }
      return defer.promise;
    }
  }
}])
```

Comment: Have you looked at the debugger? Is the username case right? Try using a function argument in find instead, could be easier to debug

Comment: Avoid the [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your are missing a `return`. The predicate (the function passed to find) returns undefined in your case, so the find algorithm does not get a "match".

Just add the `return`:

```
    let found_user = response.data.find(acc=>{
      return acc.username == user_to_find;
    })
```

You can leave it out, if you are not using curly braces

```
    let found_user = response.data.find(acc=> (
      acc.username === user_to_find;
    ))
```

I'd recommend also to use `===` (strict comparison) instead of `==` for comparison.

Comment: Oh my god. I feel so stupid, I thought that my mistake is in the promises.. I've been looking for it a whole day.. Thank you so much and sorry for the dumb question! I will follow your advice for the strict comparison, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! Don't worry, everybody did have similar issues more than once :)